# Browsable Disk Not Shown in Win10 Explorer

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, diskmanagement

Out of ideas myself so hoping someone has seen this or can throw ideas at it.

I have a Win10PRO x64 21H1 with latest monthly updates installed

- C, D, E, F Drives - all Internal
- F Drive not shown in "This PC" or down the side bar - it was until 1 week ago appx.
- Entering F:\ in address bar works
- Can browse Disk
- Applications dependent on F working

I've tried

- Re-install Disk
- Re-letter to G, at which point it appears. Move back to F, disappears again yet still usable.
- Offline/Online in Disk Management.
- Detach Disk, Boot, Reboot with Disk attached to make OS acknowledge missing.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide drives in Explorer:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/hide-physical-drives-in-windows-explorer-25e8ddaf-b6d4-e5ac-5342-ff22eaefb2f1

So, check that the corresponding registry value is not set on your computer:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrives`

Comment: Thanks for replying Swisstone! Checked, I have no "NoDrives" defined it should be showing all letters, in theory.....

Comment: @Adamski2505 Can you check for the same value in HKLM too?